# Low-tier battles with high-tier players?

Tags: world-of-tanks

My biggest shock in transition from Grille to Hummel was not in the vehicle. Sure, better traversals, higher damage, better travel times, but these were all just small quantitative changes.

The greatest shock was the change in gameplay culture in higher tier battles. Teamwork. Caution. Tactics. Sense of responsibility for safety of teammates. Specialization. I won't forget a scout I asked to hide, lying in wait patiently for good five minutes while I was busy supporting the team of heavies opposing a massive assault at a choke point. Once the heat was off, "Scout, go!" and we mopped up the rest of enemy stragglers. That was so completely unlike the suicidal maniacs rushing the enemy front lines and dying before artillery and snipers can ever get in position, so common in lower tiers.

Still, I have some lower-tier tanks (like my still favorite Pz.Sfl. IVb) I very much like for their handling and features, but as I join their low-tier battles, my blood pressure rises when I watch the gameplay style of my team. I'd love to play it with good, experienced players playing in tanks of the same tier.

I know I could join a platoon of a higher tier, but then the gun of my tank will be equivalent of pea shot on enemy armor. My poor-tier vehicle would be a hindrance to my high-level team. That's not entirely my idea of fun.

What are my other options to play low-tier matches in low-tier vehicles, but with experienced players?

Comment: Are you sure you're playing the same WoT that everyone else is? Because what I've seen of higher tier players (in random battles) is just as dreadful as in low and mid tiers

Comment: @mechatankzilla: After a time you're getting used, errors seem worse and you get that sense. Get in a Tier III vehicle and play a few matches to remind yourself just how much better you're off now. 3 suicide-spotters, 2 idlers, campers at position beyond draw distance of enemy lines, campers too self-absorbed to turn around and shot the back of scout who stops and puts 5th round into the artillery... Really, play a few low tier matches to recall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could play in a Junior Tank Company.
Additionally, leaving Assault/Encounter mode checked when playing low tiers allows you to get into those matches with your low tier tank. Since you need to have unlocked a Tier 4 and Tier 6 tank to play those game modes respectively, most players in those game modes will have more experience on average than you'd get out of a normal battle.

Answer (score 2):

Some days on the clan wars campaign map are limited to certain tiers, so you could try joining a good clan and playing with them. This limits you to playing with low tiers only on certain days though, so this option is not ideal.

The only other option there is, is to find a couple of other players who enjoy playing the low tiers and form a platoon with them. Although the majority of your team will still consist of random players, having at least a couple of others working with you can make a huge difference.

One last option you might try, which builds upon the previous one, is to get a whole bunch of skilled people together and all make them form platoons in the same tier. Then coordinate on team-speak to all have them hit the start battle button together. With luck, your platoons will end up in the same battle (although you might end up fighting each other, which can still be enjoyable). Doing this is more successful when it's not to busy on the servers. From personal experience, doing this with 5 friends of mine spread in 2 platoons we end up in the same battles around half of the time.

On a side note, although I'm happy to hear you enjoy the increased level of higher tier players there will still be plenty of high tier random games where your team won't cooperate and generally do silly stuff :).